# Nodejs fs | Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory

Tags: node.js, file, directory, filesystems

So I am using a third party project and there is the following code block:

```
// walk through /run and remove all filecontents, keeping 1 level directories.
var root = '/run';

if (fs.existsSync(root)) {
  fs.readdirSync(root).forEach(cleanFileOrDir);
}
```

where `cleanFileOrDir` is:

```
function cleanFileOrDir(f) {
  var fPath = path.join(root, f);
  if (fs.statSync(fPath).isFile()) {
    // if its a file delete it right away
    rimraf.sync(fPath);
  } else {
    // remove its contents
    rimrafKidsSync(fPath);
  }
}
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
fs.js:945
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
                 ^

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir '/run/acpid.socket'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:945:18)
    at rimrafKidsSync (/home/otis/Developer/project/dockworker/lib/controllers/dockCleaner.js:27:6)
    at cleanFileOrDir (/home/otis/Developer/project/dockworker/lib/controllers/dockCleaner.js:22:5)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/otis/Developer/project/dockworker/lib/controllers/dockCleaner.js:8:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

And the contents of my `/run/` directory are:

```
acpid.socket   crond.pid          docker       irqbalance.pid  mlocate.daily.lock  pppconfig        snapd.socket  udev     wpa_supplicant
agetty.reload  crond.reboot       docker.pid   lightdm         mount               resolvconf       sudo          udisks2  xtables.lock
alsa           cups               docker.sock  lightdm.pid     network             rsyslogd.pid     systemd       user
avahi-daemon   dbus               initctl      lock            NetworkManager      sendsigs.omit.d  thermald      utmp
containerd     dhclient-wlo1.pid  initramfs    log             plymouth            shm              tmpfiles.d    uuidd
```

I think this may have been an issue introduced by `Nodejs v6` the file system may have changed?

**Update** I modified the `cleanFileOrDir` function to look like this:

```
function cleanFileOrDir(f) {
  var fPath = path.join(root, f);
  console.log(fPath);
  if (fs.statSync(fPath).isFile()) {
    // if its a file delete it right away
    console.log('Is file');
    rimraf.sync(fPath);
  } else {
    // remove its contents
    console.log('Is directory');
    rimrafKidsSync(fPath);
  }
}
```

I now get the following output:

```
/run/NetworkManager
Is directory
/run/acpid.socket
Is directory
fs.js:945
```

So in short it is treating `/run/acpid.socket` as a directory, any idea's why this would be?

Comment: I think it would be better if you can put the fs.statSync in a try catch block if you want to skip the files which are not readable by node fs.... Also you might want to check permissions ...

Comment: @damitj07 the strange thing is that this is being run as sudo so it should be readable, and we tried chmodding the file to 777 just to be sure but nothing changed.

Comment: can you try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stat-mode) npm module ... it is more of wrapper on stat and provides some other features which might be usefull like [mode.isSocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stat-mode#modeissocketboolean-set--boolean)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "aspid.socket" - a socket, it is not a regular file and it is not a directory. List of available [tests](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats):

```
stats.isFile()
stats.isDirectory()
stats.isBlockDevice()
stats.isCharacterDevice()
stats.isFIFO()
stats.isSocket()
```

So you need to change the logic:

```
function cleanFileOrDir(f) {
  var fPath = path.join(root, f);
  var stat = fs.statSync(fPath);

  if (stat.isFile()) {
    // if its a file delete it right away
    rimraf.sync(fPath);
  } else 
  if (stat.isDirectory()){
    // remove its contents
    rimrafKidsSync(fPath);
  } else
  if (stat.isSocket()) {
    // We do something with the socket
  }

}
```